# How to aggregate several months (seasonal) from a "ts" object?

Tags: r, time-series

I'll use AirPassengers data set for reproducibility:

```
data(AirPassengers)
class(AisPassengers)
## [1] "ts"
AirPassengers
##   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1949 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 104 118
1950 115 126 141 135 125 149 170 170 158 133 114 140
1951 145 150 178 163 172 178 199 199 184 162 146 166
1952 171 180 193 181 183 218 230 242 209 191 172 194
1953 196 196 236 235 229 243 264 272 237 211 180 201
1954 204 188 235 227 234 264 302 293 259 229 203 229
1955 242 233 267 269 270 315 364 347 312 274 237 278
1956 284 277 317 313 318 374 413 405 355 306 271 306
1957 315 301 356 348 355 422 465 467 404 347 305 336
1958 340 318 362 348 363 435 491 505 404 359 310 337
1959 360 342 406 396 420 472 548 559 463 407 362 405
1960 417 391 419 461 472 535 622 606 508 461 390 432
```

Is there any way to obtain the annual seasonal average (see expected results table below) without converting the "ts" object into another class?

Right now I'm able to do this by transforming the "ts" object into xts (package xts) or into a data frame (then use package seas with mkseas).

Is there any "ts" method that I could use, so I don't have to make any transformation/conversion of the "ts" object into another class?

**Expected results, out of "ts" object:**

```
Year Average (Jun, Jul, Aug)
1949 143.667
1950 163.00
1951 192.00
...
...
```

Comment: why? transformation is reasonable trivial, and dealing with data frame is a LOT better (methods, tools, knowledge, ...)

Comment: Just trying to reduce timing... Let's say that converting/Transforming 67 Million time series is taking quite of time... Right now I'm using parallel package to go through a list of time series to get back a list  of lists where each element is a list with the aggregated values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try `aggregate.ts`.  This inputs a `"ts"` object and outputs one representing the mean of Jun, Jul and Aug of each year.  This assumes complete years:

```
aggregate(AirPassengers, 1, function(x) mean(x[6:8]))
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1949 
End = 1960 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 143.6667 163.0000 192.0000 230.0000 259.6667 286.3333 342.0000 397.3333
 [9] 451.3333 477.0000 526.3333 587.6667
```

**2)** It gets increasingly awkward if you want to allow for incomplete first and/or last years but here is a solution.  This is fairly ugly because `tapply` is converting to a matrix and then we have to manually reconstruct the `"ts"` output series from it.

```
AP2 <- window(AirPassengers, start = c(1949, 9))
unname(ts(tapply(AP2, list(floor(time(AP2)), cycle(AP2) %in% 6:8), mean)[, "TRUE"], 
   start = floor(time(AP2)[1])))

Time Series:
Start = 1949 
End = 1960 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]       NA 163.0000 192.0000 230.0000 259.6667 286.3333 342.0000 397.3333
 [9] 451.3333 477.0000 526.3333 587.6667
```

**3)** If you need to get into situations such as (2) it really would be a lot more straight forward just to convert to zoo (and back if need be).  If we don't need the NA component in the output then the line marked ## could be omitted.  Unlike (2) each operation produces a `"zoo"` series so it's much cleaner.  If we wanted a `"ts"` class output we could use `as.ts(zyr2)` .

```
library(zoo)
z <- as.zoo(AP2)
z678 <- z[cycle(z) %in% 6:8]
zyr <- aggregate(z678, floor(time(z678)), mean)
zyr2 <- merge(zyr, zoo(, unique(floor(time(z))))) ##
```

giving:

```
> zyr2
    1949     1950     1951     1952     1953     1954     1955     1956 
      NA 163.0000 192.0000 230.0000 259.6667 286.3333 342.0000 397.3333 
    1957     1958     1959     1960 
451.3333 477.0000 526.3333 587.6667
```

**4)** This could readily be done using data frames as well omitting the ## line if the NA row is not needed.  (This uses base R but sqldf, dplyr or data.table could alternately be used for the aggregation and subsetting.)  IF it were desired to convert back to ts then `ts(DF$AP2, start = DF$year[1])` .

```
DF <- data.frame(year = floor(time(AP2)), month = cycle(AP2), AP2 = c(AP2))
Ag <- aggregate(AP2 ~ year, subset(DF, month %in% 6:8), mean)
DFyr <- merge(Ag, unique(DF["year"]), all = TRUE) ##
```

giving:

```
> DFyr
   year      AP2
1  1949       NA
2  1950 163.0000
3  1951 192.0000
4  1952 230.0000
5  1953 259.6667
6  1954 286.3333
7  1955 342.0000
8  1956 397.3333
9  1957 451.3333
10 1958 477.0000
11 1959 526.3333
12 1960 587.6667
```

Comment: Have added more solutions.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try the first option with aggregate.  I'll try to use it within parLapply in a cluster, I have ~67 M of time series from which I want to get this type of aggregation.  So I hope something like this works:  `vlist<- parLapply(cl, myListTS, aggregateTS)`  Where 'aggregateTS' will contain the aggregate function.  Thanks G. Grothendieck

Comment: If speed is an issue then data table tends to be fast.  For complete years (or incomplete years that do not need NA fillling) try this where `DF` is as in (4): `library(data.table); as.data.table(DF)[month %in% 6:8, list(AP2 = mean(AP2)), by = year]`  .

Comment: Thanks...  I have been using data.table, it's just that I'm getting as data source a list with 67 M  ts objects.  Right now I'm actually running a very similar approach as the one you mention:  Converting ts into data.frame and then converting into data table to get aggregation...This is taking a long time to finish for that number of list elements (2 days and counting with 120 cores using parLapply).  So I was wondering if avoiding  "as.xxx" conversions could speed up the task...

Comment: Suggest you benchmark different methods on a smaller amount of data to know for sure what is fastest.

Comment: I was doing a simple/micro one with AirPassengers... `ptm <- proc.time();
DA <- aggregate(AP2, 1, function(x) mean(x[6:8]))[1:12];
proc.time() - ptm;` 
vs `ptm <- proc.time();
DF <- data.frame(year = floor(time(AP2)), month = cycle(AP2), AP2 = c(AP2));
DT<-as.data.table(DF)[month %in% 6:8, list(AP2 = mean(AP2)), by = year];
proc.time() - ptm;`
First: 0.0009 and Second 0.004 on my laptop, I'll try a more realistic by taking a sample of the 67M...

Comment: Suggest you look at the rbenchmark and microbenchmark packages.